# $_POST not working

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to run the below query which basically create a submit button. However when I am trying to click the Accept Request button it is not resolving the if condition and directly echo what is written in else condition. 
Can someone help why this would be happening?

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['acceptrequest'.$user_from]))
  {
    echo "you are now freind !";
  } else 
  {
    echo 'Error in reading - acceptrequest'.$user_from;
  }
?>


<form action = "friend_request.php" method = "POST">
<input type="submit" name = "acceptrequest<?php echo $user_from;?>"   
       value="Accept Request" style = "margin-left: 5px;" />
<input type="submit" name = "ignorerequest<?php echo $user_from;?>"  
       value="Ignore Request" style = "margin-left: 5px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Don't put spaces between attribute names and values in the HTML tags. It should be `<form action="friend_request.php" method="POST">`

Comment: where is `$user_from` initially being defined? this should be throwing you an undefined user_from variable notice.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: you're not helping here by not interacting. I am closing this tab now. @ me if you need me. *ciao!*

Comment: Add the code where `$user_from` is set, please.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins having spaces between name and value is not a problem (at least it should be one). And it is valid according to the specs [W3C: Attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/syntax.html#attributes-0) `[...]The attribute name, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by the attribute value, [...]`

Comment: the $user_from variable resolving as when ever I am submitting the button it showing me "Error in reading - acceptrequestpbhatt1984@gmail.com" .. for some reason the if part - if(isset($_POST['acceptrequest'.$user_from])) is not resolving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you ought not use variables to define the name of a form input.

Specifically because of the "variable" nature of variables, you can't be sure that the name posted will match the name you're looking for.

In order to keep your application stateless, you should instead post the variable kn its own hidden input.

Below, I modified your form to post `user_from` as its own input, separate from `acceptrequest` and `ignorerequest`.

This should fix any state issues that you were experiencing before.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['acceptrequest')) {
      echo "You are now friend with {$_POST['user_from']}!";
  } else if (isset($_POST['ignorerequest')) {
      echo "You ignored the request from {$_POST['user_from']}!";
  } else {
      echo 'Error in reading - acceptrequest'.$user_from;
  }
?>


<form action = "friend_request.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="user_from"
       value="<?php echo $user_from;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="acceptrequest"   
       value="Accept Request" style = "margin-left: 5px;" />
<input type="submit" name="ignorerequest"  
       value="Ignore Request" style = "margin-left: 5px;" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You haven't set all variables. Try to define that and use:   $

So create something like: $acceptrequest == something